# Restore Hidden Buttons

Tags: android

I have `ImageButton` `ArrayList` with 9 buttons, `onClick` the button disappears with `setVisibility(View.GONE)` how can I detect when all buttons are destroyed and restore them?

```
    final ArrayList<ImageButton> bList  = new ArrayList<>();
    bList.add((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1));
    bList.add((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2));
    bList.add((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton3));
    bList.add((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton4));
    bList.add((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton5));
    bList.add((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton6));
    bList.add((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton7));
    bList.add((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton8));
    bList.add((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton9));

    bList.get(0).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            boxNum(0);
        }
    });
    bList.get(1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            boxNum(1);
        }
    });
    bList.get(2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            boxNum(2);
        }
    });
    // so on.. till num. 8
```

Comment: Please show more of your code what you are trying to do. It is not clear from your description.

Comment: Isn't the question simple? Why need to show the code for this? But okay since you asking

Comment: question updated @ruben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a counter variable which counts to 9. Once it's nine it sets all button's `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`